# Python - Parse Text from One Column into Multiple Columns

Tags: python, regex, pandas, parsing, text

I have an Excel file that has two columns. The first is useful identifying information while the second is a block of text that can vary from row to row. Within that column, there are pieces of information I would like to parse out into separate columns depending on the availability. For example:

| Reference | Block of text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Number: there are four people Location: this happened in downtown Time: this happened at midnight |

I would like to turn this into:

| Reference | Block of text | Number | Location | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Number: there are four people Location: this happened in downtown Time: this happened at midnight | there are four people | this happened in downtown | this happened at midnight |

How might I achieve this using Python?

Comment: See my reply, please consider as marking a resolution.

Comment: Nikhil, you should follow answers to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, it works when splitters are in any order or any of the information is missing.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

SPLITTERS = ['Number:', 'Location:', 'Time:']
SPLITTERS_PAIRS = [(s1, s2) for s1 in SPLITTERS for s2 in SPLITTERS if s1 != s2]

BLOCK_OF_TEXT_COLUMN_NAME = 'Block of text'
REFERENCE_COLUMN_NAME = 'Reference'


def extract_info(row) -> Tuple[str]:

    info: Dict = {}
    text_in: str = row[BLOCK_OF_TEXT_COLUMN_NAME] if row[BLOCK_OF_TEXT_COLUMN_NAME] else ''

    for splitter_pair in SPLITTERS_PAIRS:

        re_text_in_between = re.search(f'{splitter_pair[0]}(.*){splitter_pair[1]}', text_in)
        text_in_between = re_text_in_between.group(1) if re_text_in_between else None

        if text_in_between:
            third_splitter = [s for s in SPLITTERS if s not in splitter_pair][0]
            if third_splitter in text_in_between:
                pass
            else:
                info[splitter_pair[0]] = text_in_between.strip()

    # we now add the third splitter, which is the last one appearing in the string
    missing_splitter = [s for s in SPLITTERS if s not in info.keys()][0]
    info[missing_splitter] = text_in.split(missing_splitter)[-1].strip() if text_in.split(missing_splitter)[-1] else None

    # in case a splitter was not present in the text, we add as null
    missing_splitters = [s for s in SPLITTERS if s not in info.keys()]

    for ms in missing_splitters:
        info[ms] = None

    return info[SPLITTERS[0]], info[SPLITTERS[1]], info[SPLITTERS[2]]


df = pd.DataFrame({REFERENCE_COLUMN_NAME:
                       [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   BLOCK_OF_TEXT_COLUMN_NAME:
                       ['Number: there are four people Location: this happened in downtown Time: this happened at midnight',
                       'Location: this happened in Rome Time: this happened at noon Number: there are three people ',
                       'Number: there are eight people',
                        None]})

df[SPLITTERS[0]], df[SPLITTERS[1]], df[SPLITTERS[2]] = \
    zip(*df.apply(extract_info, axis=1))
```